# Trying to display TempData msg with Ajax POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

Hello I'm a bit stuck to display an alert msg with latest version of asp.net core 8 MVC.
I have an edit post form with Ajax and this is the code.

View code:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit book";
    var notification = TempData["Notification"];
}


@if (notification != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
       @notification
    </div>
}


// Ajax script

var url = '@Url.Action("EditBook", "Account")';
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
        model
    },
    success: function (response, xhr) {
        if (response.redirectToUrl != undefined) {
            window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;
        } else {

        }

    }
});
```

The end of my POST controller where I manage my alerts

```
if (result == 1)
{
    TempData["Notification"] = "The book has been published successfully!";
    return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Books", "Account") });
} else // Error
{
    TempData["Notificacion"] = "There was an error processing your request, please contact with support";
    return View(model);
}
```

Doing this with successful message works good because it is a redirect but I don't want to loose the model and that's why I'm trying to return the same view with model.

Edit
Fixed was my gallery js breaking it. After disable, it works now.

Comment: Could you show  the full code so that we can reproduce the problem ? If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell.

Comment: Ok, I'll make a simple reproducible example later.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Create partial as _Notification view
@if (TempData["success"] != null)
{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        toastr.success('@TempData["success"]');
    </script>
}
@if (TempData["error"] != null)
{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        toastr.error('@TempData["success"]');
    </script>
}
   Add below link and code in layout 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/g28lhnxtlihu4l4a381gw7tz47voznshwbi10lmsvlekrfme/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin">
     <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        <partial name="_Notification" />
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>
   Add in controller
TempData["success"] = "Category updated successfully";
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your example but unfortunately is not working. Maybe I need to add something more to Ajax?

Comment: Probably your code works good, I was able to fix my issue. I had a js gallery breaking page functionality.